# How to clear my BezierCurve vector to stop writing coordinates on top of each other?

Tags: c++, vector, line, glut, bezier

I have built a Bezier Curve tool and each time the coordinates for each curve segment are calculated they are stored in a vector. Every single frame I am adding the entire curve's points on it over and over again. That is, frame 1, might have { p1, p2, p3 } then frame 2, it would have { p1, p2, **p3, p1**, p2, p3 } and so on. This would cause the line to loop back on itself when the loop at the end of the render function draws lines between the points p3 and p1. I am struggling to find where and how I should clear my BezierCurve vector between frames. Clearing after `glClear()` or before `glSwapBuffers()` only shows the previously drawn curve segment and has a straight line between points.
**I basically want the straight line in between points to go away and I know why it is happening.** My code is below:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//Point class for taking the points
class Point {
public:
    float x, y;

    void setxy(float x2, float y2)
    {
        x = x2; y = y2;
    }

    //operator overloading for '=' sign
    const Point& operator=(const Point& rPoint)
    {
        x = rPoint.x;
        y = rPoint.y;
        return *this;
    }

};

int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;
vector<Point> Points;
Point Tangent;
Point inverseTangent;
Point cursorLocationLive;
int TangentsSize = 0;
vector<Point> Tangents(TangentsSize);
vector<Point> inverseTangents(TangentsSize);
vector<Point> BezierCurve;
bool MouseReleased = false;

void drawDot(Point p1)
{
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(p1.x, p1.y);
    glEnd();
}

void drawLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex2f(p1.x, p1.y);
    glVertex2f(p2.x, p2.y);
    glEnd();
}

float interpolate(float n1, float n2, float perc)
{
    float diff = n2 - n1;

    return n1 + (diff * perc);
}

void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
    {
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            MouseReleased = false;
            // Store points into Points vector on click
            Point point;
            point.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
            Points.push_back(point);

            // Tangents are set to the cursor position
            Tangent.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
            inverseTangent.x = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].x) - Tangent.x;
            inverseTangent.y = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].y) - Tangent.y;

            /*Add new element to Tangent & inverseTangent so when we draw the curve
            the tangents are accessed at the right index*/
            TangentsSize++;
        }
        else if (state == GLUT_UP)
        {
            MouseReleased = true;
            // Upon mouse release store tangent and inverse tangent into separate vectors
            Tangents.push_back(Tangent);
            inverseTangents.push_back(inverseTangent);
        }
    }
}

void passiveMotion(int x, int y)
{
    // Sets the location of cursor while moving with no buttons pressed
    cursorLocationLive.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    // Sets the coordinates of the tangents when mouse moves with a button held down
    Tangent.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
    inverseTangent.x = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].x) - Tangent.x;
    inverseTangent.y = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].y) - Tangent.y;
}

void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw main points in red
    glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i++)
    {
        drawDot(Points[i]);
    }

    // If there is a starting point draw a line to cursor from last drawn point in passive motion
    if (Points.size() > 0)
    {
        glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
        drawLine(Points[Points.size() - 1], cursorLocationLive);
    }

    // Draw live tangent dots in green
    glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
    drawDot(Tangent);
    drawDot(inverseTangent);
    // Draw live tangent lines in blue
    glColor3f(0, 0, 255);
    drawLine(Tangent, inverseTangent);

    for (int i = 0; i < Tangents.size(); i++)
    {
        // Draw stored tangent dots in green
        glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
        drawDot(Tangents[i]);
        drawDot(inverseTangents[i]);
        // Draw stored tangent lines in blue
        glColor3f(0, 0, 255);
        drawLine(Tangents[i], inverseTangents[i]);
    }

    // Loop through all points
    for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i++)
    {
        // If there are two points draw the first segment
        if (Points.size() == 2)
        {
            // p1 is the start of the curve set at first point
            Point p1;
            p1 = Points[0];

            float i;
            // Calculate curve coordinates
            for (float j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                i = j / 100;
                // The Green Lines
                float xa = interpolate(Points[0].x, inverseTangents[0].x, i);
                float ya = interpolate(Points[0].y, inverseTangents[0].y, i);
                float xb = interpolate(inverseTangents[0].x, inverseTangent.x, i);
                float yb = interpolate(inverseTangents[0].y, inverseTangent.y, i);
                float xc = interpolate(inverseTangent.x, Points[1].x, i);
                float yc = interpolate(inverseTangent.y, Points[1].y, i);

                // The Blue Line
                float xm = interpolate(xa, xb, i);
                float ym = interpolate(ya, yb, i);
                float xn = interpolate(xb, xc, i);
                float yn = interpolate(yb, yc, i);

                // The Black Dot
                float x2 = interpolate(xm, xn, i);
                float y2 = interpolate(ym, yn, i);

                Point p2;
                p2.setxy(x2, y2);

                drawLine(p1, p2);

                p1 = p2;

                // Prevents curves generated during mouse motion from being stored
                if (MouseReleased)
                {
                    // Store curvature into Bezier Points
                    BezierCurve.push_back(p2);
                }
            }
        }
        // Second segment onwards
        else if (Points.size() > 2)
        {
            // p1 is the start of the curve set to second last point
            Point p1;
            p1 = Points[Points.size() - 2];

            float i;
            // Calculate curve coordinates
            for (float j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                i = j / 100;
                // The Green Lines
                float xa = interpolate(Points[Points.size() - 2].x, Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].x, i);
                float ya = interpolate(Points[Points.size() - 2].y, Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].y, i);
                float xb = interpolate(Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].x, inverseTangent.x, i);
                float yb = interpolate(Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].y, inverseTangent.y, i);
                float xc = interpolate(inverseTangent.x, Points[Points.size() - 1].x, i);
                float yc = interpolate(inverseTangent.y, Points[Points.size() - 1].y, i);

                // The Blue Line
                float xm = interpolate(xa, xb, i);
                float ym = interpolate(ya, yb, i);
                float xn = interpolate(xb, xc, i);
                float yn = interpolate(yb, yc, i);

                // The Black Dot
                float x2 = interpolate(xm, xn, i);
                float y2 = interpolate(ym, yn, i);

                Point p2;
                p2.setxy(x2, y2);

                drawLine(p1, p2);

                p1 = p2;

                // Prevents curves generated during mouse motion from being stored
                if (MouseReleased)
                {
                    // Store curvature into Bezier Points
                    BezierCurve.push_back(p2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Draw all bezier curvature
    for (int i = 1; i < BezierCurve.size(); i++)
    {
        drawLine(BezierCurve[i - 1], BezierCurve[i]);
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int)
{
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, timer, 0);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("Bezier Curve");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutIdleFunc(myDisplay);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotion);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
    glPointSize(3);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 640.0, 0.0, 500.0);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So there is too many points added per frame and this is causing the line to loop...What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: @jackw11111 I basically want the line to go away. This happens because the curve segment's points are written multiple times over. For example in frame 1 it is {p1, p2, p3} and then in frame two, it becomes {p1, p2, p3, p1, p2, p3}. The line occurs because of the loop and is being drawn from p3 to p1. I only want the curve segment's coordinates to be stored once after being drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to detect when mouse click changes from down to up:

```
bool prevMouse;
...
// at the end of Display()
prevMouse = MouseReleased;
```

Then we check when mouse click changes from pressed to released and add lines to `BezierCurve`:

```
if (PrevMouse == 0 && MouseReleased)
{
    // Store curvature into Bezier Points
    BezierCurve.push_back(p2);
}
```

The two code paths, `if (Points.size() == 2)`, and `else if (Points.size() > 2)` inside the for loop can be simplified to `if (Points.size() >= 2)` and for that matter the for loop is extraneous, we don't need to update the bezier curve for any of the previous points, just the curve between the two newest points, `Points[Points.size() - 2]` and `Points[Points.size() - 1]`.

The final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//Point class for taking the points
class Point {
public:
    float x, y;

    void setxy(float x2, float y2)
    {
        x = x2; y = y2;
    }

    //operator overloading for '=' sign
    const Point& operator=(const Point& rPoint)
    {
        x = rPoint.x;
        y = rPoint.y;
        return *this;
    }

};

int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;
vector<Point> Points;
Point Tangent;
Point inverseTangent;
Point cursorLocationLive;
int TangentsSize = 0;
vector<Point> Tangents(TangentsSize);
vector<Point> inverseTangents(TangentsSize);
vector<Point> BezierCurve;
bool MouseReleased = false;
bool PrevMouse = false;

void drawDot(Point p1)
{
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(p1.x, p1.y);
    glEnd();
}

void drawLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex2f(p1.x, p1.y);
    glVertex2f(p2.x, p2.y);
    glEnd();
}

float interpolate(float n1, float n2, float perc)
{
    float diff = n2 - n1;

    return n1 + (diff * perc);
}

void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
    {
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            MouseReleased = false;
            // Store points into Points vector on click
            Point point;
            point.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
            Points.push_back(point);

            // Tangents are set to the cursor position
            Tangent.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
            inverseTangent.x = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].x) - Tangent.x;
            inverseTangent.y = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].y) - Tangent.y;

            /*Add new element to Tangent & inverseTangent so when we draw the curve
            the tangents are accessed at the right index*/
            TangentsSize++;
        }
        else if (state == GLUT_UP)
        {
            MouseReleased = true;
            // Upon mouse release store tangent and inverse tangent into separate vectors
            Tangents.push_back(Tangent);
            inverseTangents.push_back(inverseTangent);
        }
    }
}

void passiveMotion(int x, int y)
{
    // Sets the location of cursor while moving with no buttons pressed
    cursorLocationLive.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    // Sets the coordinates of the tangents when mouse moves with a button held down
    Tangent.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
    inverseTangent.x = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].x) - Tangent.x;
    inverseTangent.y = (2 * Points[Points.size() - 1].y) - Tangent.y;
}

void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw main points in red
    glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i++)
    {
        drawDot(Points[i]);
    }

    // If there is a starting point draw a line to cursor from last drawn point in passive motion
    if (Points.size() > 0)
    {
        glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
        drawLine(Points[Points.size() - 1], cursorLocationLive);
    }

    // Draw live tangent dots in green
    glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
    drawDot(Tangent);
    drawDot(inverseTangent);
    // Draw live tangent lines in blue
    glColor3f(0, 0, 255);
    drawLine(Tangent, inverseTangent);

    for (int i = 0; i < Tangents.size(); i++)
    {
        // Draw stored tangent dots in green
        glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
        drawDot(Tangents[i]);
        drawDot(inverseTangents[i]);
        // Draw stored tangent lines in blue
        glColor3f(0, 0, 255);
        drawLine(Tangents[i], inverseTangents[i]);
    }

    // Loop through all points
    if (Points.size() >= 2)
    {
        // p1 is the start of the curve set to second last point
        Point p1;
        p1 = Points[Points.size() - 2];

        float i;
        // Calculate curve coordinates
        for (float j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
        {
            i = j / 100;
            // The Green Lines
            float xa = interpolate(Points[Points.size() - 2].x, Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].x, i);
            float ya = interpolate(Points[Points.size() - 2].y, Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].y, i);
            float xb = interpolate(Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].x, inverseTangent.x, i);
            float yb = interpolate(Tangents[TangentsSize - 2].y, inverseTangent.y, i);
            float xc = interpolate(inverseTangent.x, Points[Points.size() - 1].x, i);
            float yc = interpolate(inverseTangent.y, Points[Points.size() - 1].y, i);

            // The Blue Line
            float xm = interpolate(xa, xb, i);
            float ym = interpolate(ya, yb, i);
            float xn = interpolate(xb, xc, i);
            float yn = interpolate(yb, yc, i);

            // The Black Dot
            float x2 = interpolate(xm, xn, i);
            float y2 = interpolate(ym, yn, i);

            Point p2;
            p2.setxy(x2, y2);

            drawLine(p1, p2);

            p1 = p2;

            // Prevents curves generated during mouse motion from being stored
            if (PrevMouse == 0 && MouseReleased)
            {
                // Store curvature into Bezier Points
                BezierCurve.push_back(p2);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << BezierCurve.size() << std::endl;
    
    PrevMouse = MouseReleased;

    // Draw all bezier curvature
    for (int i = 1; i < BezierCurve.size(); i++)
    {
        drawLine(BezierCurve[i - 1], BezierCurve[i]);
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int)
{
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, timer, 0);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("Bezier Curve");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutIdleFunc(myDisplay);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotion);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
    glPointSize(3);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 640.0, 0.0, 500.0);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

[image: bezier]

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to study what you said for a while so I can understand it better. However, when I compile I get this error:  uninitialized local variable i used for lines 165 and 216.

Comment: I was just modifying the code and didn't see that my compiler was compiling the code even though `float i` was shadowing `int i` from the loop. But the idea is that when 1 is used as an interpolating value, it will interpolate to the first point, thus creating the loop, so if you ignore i when `i == 1`, it wont draw the straight line.

Comment: Could you explain why the straight line doesn't appear now? Also on lines 124 & 175 I had to change the operator to `>=` from `==`.

Comment: I have fixed that bug and edited the code above. I couldn't understand why the `else if (Points.size() > 2)` section was running multiple times (not hugely familiar with bezier curve maths) so I just used a `break`. Its a bit of a hack but hope it serves your purposes well enough. Thanks.

Comment: So when you were debugging the `else if(Points.size() > 2)` section it was the cause of the loop so we are manually leaving the section instead? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, so I had the divisions set to 5 (not 100) and was printing the size of `BezierCurve` and noticing that it was growing something like 6,18,36, etc.. every time a new curve was added, and noticed that code section was looping too many times and producing `{p1,p2 ,p3, p1, p2, p3}` and was actually the cause of the line loop, so breaking made sure it ran only once ie. `{p1, p2, p3}` in the loop. I'm still trying to understand why that is the case.

Comment: Another question I have is what does the live bezier if's do different to the regular bezier if's? Why do we require another set?

Comment: We want to keep the `BezierCurve` data around permanently, but we only want to keep the live bezier curve data as along as the mouse is pressed, and reset the vector otherwise. There are likely better ways to do it, it was just the way that seemed to make sense.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the purpose of LiveBezierCurve as opposed to just doing it all in BezierCurve. Do you think you could explain it again?

Comment: Very sorry. That was old code. So `drawLine` inside `drawCurve` is responsible from drawing the live curve. When mouse is released, `newCurve` gets appended to `BezierCurve` to be rendered every frame.

Comment: I still haven't figured out why `break` is important but i am AFK for an hour or so. Then I will see if I can understand why. Thanks.

Comment: Bro you have talent though, I'm glad there's more people who are well versed at this.

Comment: I have fixed the code, it was much simpler than I thought, sorry for the trial-and-error edits, the code took me a bit to figure out what was going on. Thanks again.

Comment: I wanted to ask why we have to draw another entire set of curves for mouse motion? What is the benefit?

Comment: It isn't anymore, its doing exactly like the code in the question, but now it isn't adding data every frame, and not drawing the line loop.

Comment: Why is `PrevMouse` needed? Doesn't `MouseReleased` do the same thing?

Comment: `PrevMouse` is only 1 when `MouseReleased` changes from `0` to `1`.  So  when its briefly `1`, ie. for a split second when you release the mouse button, it updates the curve data.